# LIBGDX Game Memory Leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks, libgdx

I'm developing a Game for Android with LibGDX. If i start my Game it work but i Debug the Memory Usage with this Methods

```
Gdx.app.log("Java Heap", String.valueOf(Gdx.app.getJavaHeap()));
Gdx.app.log("Native Heap", String.valueOf(Gdx.app.getNativeHeap()));
```

The Java Heap is constant but the Native Heap climb in the high. I do 15-20 actions on the screen with Textbutton, labels ect. and import .png files for the images. I dipose this files with the dispose() Method but the Native Heap climb higher and i dont know what fill the Memory.

Now is my question give it a way to Debug what is in the Memory Usage or give it a way to clear all Native Heap out of dispose() ? If anyone now a way to help please tell it.

Answer (score 2):

The way i try to optimize game using eclipse for android is through `DDMS`. There are two key tabs, `HEAP` and `ALLOCATION TRACKER`.
`Heap` will let you know how much heap memory is consumed at that moment of time.
`Allocation Tracker` will keep track of memory allocation, as well as the class stack trace of who is allocating that memory.

Also one golden rule, `Never ever create new objects in render method.`